# Execute SQL script in Entity Framework & convert the result to JSON

Tags: sql, json, entity-framework

Hey Guys I want to execute this SQL script in Entity Framework & return the result in `JSONResult` format to access in jQuery.. Please help!!!

My Entity Framework model contains the tables & databases mentioned in SQL script

THANKS :-)

```
DECLARE @listCol VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT  @listCol = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  '], [' + [PSize]
                           FROM     Pattern
                         FOR
                           XML PATH('')
                         ), 1, 2, '') + ']'
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT PColour as Colour_Size_Matrix, PSize, PCode
            FROM Pattern
            ) src
PIVOT (Count(PCode) FOR PSize
IN (' + @listCol + ')) AS pvt'
EXECUTE ( @query )
```

Answer (score 0):

You needs to get the query result in a list of your models and return like Json:

```
var context = new YourContext(); 
var results = (from c in context.PCoulor select c).Contains(yourValue).ToList();
return Json(results , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: How can I execute this Query in EntityFramework or say Linq?
I'm using MVC 4